# Subplot two images with a vertical separator

Tags: image, matlab, line, matlab-figure, subplot

I'm trying to create a figure with an image on the left (original image) and an image on the right (warped image) and a vertical line separating them, like this:

[image]

I've tried this by creating axes, without ticks and labels. Then drawing a line from bottom to top and applying `hold on` and finally `subplot` the two images.

My code:

```
origImage = imread('F-original.png');
tform = affine2d([1 0 0; .5 1 0; 0 0 1]);
warpedImage = imwarp(origImage, tform, 'interp', 'bilinear');

axes('Position', [0 0 1 1], 'XTick', NaN, 'YTick', NaN);
line([1/2 1/2], [0 1], 'Color', 'k')
axes(gca)
hold on

subplot(1, 2, 1)
imshow(origImage)

subplot(1, 2, 2)
imshow(warpedImage)
```

But what actually happens is: the line flashes for a split second, but then disappears and all that can be seen are the subplots.

How to make this work?

Comment: Try this: keep the two subplots, turn the figure background into white, add the line via `annotation`.

Comment: @Dev-iL That solves it! I can even get rid of the `axes`,  `hold on` etc. Thank you very much. Can I ask you to please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for the accept :)

Comment: maybe also take a look at `montage()`. There's no vertical separator, but you can specify the bordersize and more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve that result you should use an [`annotation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html), which is a graphical object on the **figure level** (i.e. not confined to a specific axes, so doesn't require `hold on` etc.).

Here's an example:

```matlab
function q54617073
% Prepare images:
origImage = imread('ngc6543a.jpg');
tform = affine2d([1 0 0; .5 1 0; 0 0 1]);
warpedImage = imwarp(origImage, tform, 'interp', 'bilinear');
% Create a figure with a white background:
figure('Color','w');
% Plot the two images:
subplot(1, 2, 1); imshow(origImage);
subplot(1, 2, 2); imshow(warpedImage);
% Add the Line
annotation('line', [0.52 0.52], [0.2 0.8], 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 3);
```

Resulting in:

[image]